# How can I retrieve the status of a scheduled task using schtasks?

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

When I run this:

```
schtasks.exe /query  /tn "GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA"
```

I get this:

```
Folder: \
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== ===============
GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA                N/A                    Disabled
```

Is there any way to retrieve Status only?

Answer (score 4):

Try `schtasks /query` with `/v` option for verbose output and `/fo list` for list format.
Then filter results with `find` command.

```
schtasks /query /tn "GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA" /v /fo list | find "Status:"
```

You get string like this

```
Status:         Running
```

To extract value of status use `for` command:

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %a in ('schtasks /query /tn "GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA" /v /fo list ^| find "Status:"') do @echo %a
```

- To use in batch file replace `%a` with `%%a`
- To escape symbols like `|` or `>` in `for` command use `^`

Answer (score 3):

Unless you really have to use `schtasks.exe`, use PowerShell with all its superior output and formatting options:

```
Get-ScheduledTask | ? TaskName -eq GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA | Select State | ft -AutoSize
```

or

```
(Get-ScheduledTask | Where TaskName -eq GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA ).State
```

Comment: This does not work on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there any way to retrieve Status only?

Use the following command:

```
for /f "usebackq skip=3 tokens=4" %a in (`schtasks.exe /query /tn "GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA"`) do @echo %a
```

Notes:

- `skip=3` - ignore the header lines
- `tokens=4` - grab the 4th token (the value in the status column)
- To use in a batch file, replace `%a` with `%%a`

Example usage:

```
F:\test>schtasks.exe /query  /tn "GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA"

Folder: \
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== ===============
GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA                03/02/2016 12:17:00    Ready

F:\test>for /f "usebackq skip=3 tokens=4" %a in (`schtasks.exe /query /tn "GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA"`) do @echo %a
Ready
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [schtasks](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) - Create / edit a Scheduled Job/Task. The job can be created on the local or a remote computer.

Comment: Tried this. It works good only for task without `space` in name. When there are spaces in task name, this does not work. Not yet tried, but It may work if I try to adjust `tokens` values by counting spaces in output.

Comment: @Sandeep Hmm. Tricky. There are some possible workaround in [Windows Batch file count numbers of tokens - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717661/windows-batch-file-count-numbers-of-tokens)

Comment: Thank you, this works. Simply adjust the number of tokens if your scheduled task has spaces, e.g. `for /f "usebackq skip=3 tokens=7" %a in (\`schtasks.exe /query /tn "Refresh Dashboard Cache"\`) do @echo %a`

Comment: @wp78de: [no need to count tokens](https://superuser.com/a/1474807/217811)

Answer (score 1):

I've searched for a good answer to this, and found some things that got me close.  What I ended up with is the following.

```
$taskName="SomeTask"
$serverName="yourserver"
$status = (schtasks.exe /query /tn "$taskName" /s $serverName /v /fo CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object -Property "Status").Status
```

If you want all of the items from the task, you can do something similar to the following...

```
$task= schtasks.exe /query /tn "$taskName" /s $serverName  /v /fo CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object
```

Then you can select whichever property you want to work with...

```
$task.Status
$task."Last Result"
```

Remember to use quotes around the properties with spaces in them!

To clarify, my response is using Powershell when Get-ScheduledTask is not available, which it wouldn't be if running Windows 7, or Windows Server 2008.  While one answer does provide a way to get the status, I feel like this method is easier to understand and work with. Even more so if someone might be interested in getting other properties of the scheduled task without having to parse which column the property happens to be in.  In short, my answer is the solution that *I* was looking for, so I thought I would share it for other like minded individuals.

Comment: (1) This is PowerShell, right?  When the question (and many of the answers) refer to CMD, it’s nice to mention explicitly that your answer uses PowerShell.  (2) There are a couple of PowerShell answers already; one that uses `Get-ScheduledTask` and one that uses `(schtasks /query …) -split`.  How is your answer better than those?    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a Powershell script using Windows 7 and can't use `Get-ScheduledTask`, you could consider using:

`$status = ((schtasks /query /S 'yourServer' /TN yourTask)[4] -split ' +')[2]`

It looks like this:

```
### Running this:
schtasks /query /S 'yourServer' /TN yourTask
### Leads to the output below.

Folder: \
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status         
======================================== ====================== ===============
yourTask                                 N/A                    Running   

### Running this:
$status = ((schtasks /query /S 'yourServer' /TN yourTask)[4] -split ' +')[2]
Write-Host "$($status)"
### Leads to the output below

Running
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works also for tasknames with space(s) in their name:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %a in ('schtasks.exe /query /tn "GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA" /fo csv /nh') do echo %~a
```

As we output a csv (**c**omma **s**eparated **v**alues) (`/fo`rmat `csv`) and use `delims=,`, spaces don't matter any more.  `/nh` stands for "**n**o **h**eader", so no need for `skip=`.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot why, it's been years, but I ended up parsing the "/fo list" format, rather than "/fo csv", after initially thinking "/fo csv" would be my salvation.

There's some more info about this in my blog, but I won't link, because I don't want to be labeled a "vampire" here, right now I'm listed on the front page of Google (actually #1 right now, this hit was #3 for me) for searches about parsing schtasks.exe output, powershelladmin / Svendsen Tech:

Here's the code I used to retrieve tasks from servers, with PowerShell version 2 on some of them, so I couldn't use Get-ScheduledTask. Along with some examples of handy filtering you can toy with to suit your needs.

```
@(foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Processing $Computer ..."
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
    $TaskText = schtasks.exe /query /s $Computer /fo list /v
    if (-not $?) {
        Write-Warning -Message "$Computer`: schtasks.exe failed"
        continue
    }
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
    $TaskText = $TaskText -join "`n"
    @(
    foreach ($m in @([regex]::Matches($TaskText, '(?ms)^Folder:[\t ]*([^\n]+)\n(.+)'))) {
        $Folder = $m.Groups[1].Value
        foreach ($FolderEntries in @($m.Groups[2].Value -split "\n\n")) {
            foreach ($Inner in $FolderEntries) {
                [regex]::Matches([string] $Inner, '(?m)^((?:Repeat:\s)?(?:Until:\s)?[^:]+):[\t ]+(.*)') |
                    ForEach-Object -Begin { $h = @{}; $h.'Folder' = [string] $Folder  } -Process {
                        $h.($_.Groups[1].Value) = $_.Groups[2].Value
                    } -End { New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $h }
            }
        }
    }) | Where-Object { $_.Folder -notlike '\Microsoft*' -and `
        $_.'Run As User' -notmatch '^(?:SYSTEM|LOCAL SERVICE|Everyone|Users|Administrators|INTERACTIVE)$' -and `
        $_.'Task To Run' -notmatch 'COM handler' } #|
        #Select HostName, Folder, 'Run As User', 'Task To Run', 'Schedule Type', 'Logon Mode' #, * #| ft -AutoSize
}) # | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Path oracleservertasks.csv
```

Example output can be seen in this image on my blog: https://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki_files/Parse-schtasks_exe.png

Answer (score -1):

Add `/fo csv` to the `schtasks` command to change its output format to CSV.

Then use [CSVFix](http://neilb.bitbucket.org/csvfix/) to filter the required column with `-f 3` argument and skip the field-name record with `-ifn`.

```
schtasks.exe /query /tn "GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA" | csvfix order -ifn -f 3
```